# FastAPI deployed on Heroku, Internal Server Error when connecting to MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, heroku, fastapi

[image: Heroku logs]I want to connect fastapi with my mongodb database, it works fine when I am running my backend on localhost. But when I deployed this code on heroku and trying the methods it returns "Internal Server Error".
I checked again found that put, post and delete methods are working somehow, I mean it is creating and updating data on the database but giving internal server error at the same time. So I am unable to read data from the database, only can create, update and delete.

db.py

```
    from model import *
    import motor.motor_asyncio
    
    DATABASE_URI = "mongodb+srv://mongodb_url"
    client = motor.motor_asyncio.AsyncIOMotorClient(DATABASE_URI)
    database = client.todoList
    collection = database.todo


async def fetch_one_todo(nanoid):
    document = await collection.find_one({"nanoid": nanoid})
    return document


async def fetch_all_todos():
    todos = []
    cursor = collection.find({})
    async for document in cursor:
        todos.append(ToDo(**document))
    return todos


async def create_todo(todo):
    document = todo
    await collection.insert_one(document)
    return document


async def update_todo(nanoid, data):
    await collection.update_one({"nanoid": nanoid}, {"$set": data})
    document = await collection.find_one({"nanoid": nanoid})
    return document


async def remove_todo(nanoid):
    await collection.delete_one({"nanoid": nanoid})
    return True
```

main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from db import *
from model import ToDo
from UpdateModel import UpdateToDo


app = FastAPI()

origins = ["*"]
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hi!"}


@app.get("/api/get-todo")
async def get_todo():
    response = await fetch_all_todos()
    return response


@app.get("/api/get-todo/{nanoid}", response_model=ToDo)
async def get_todo_id(nanoid):
    todo = await fetch_one_todo(nanoid)
    if todo:
        return todo
    raise HTTPException(404)


@app.post("/api/add-todo", response_model=ToDo)
async def post_todo(todo: ToDo):
    response = await create_todo(todo.dict())
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(400, "Something went wrong")


@app.put("/api/update-todo/{nanoid}", response_model=ToDo)
async def put_todo(nanoid: str, updatetodo: UpdateToDo):
    response = await update_todo(nanoid, updatetodo.dict())
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(404, 'wrong')


@app.delete("/api/delete-todo/{nanoid}")
async def delete_todo(nanoid):
    response = await remove_todo(nanoid)
    if response:
        return response
    raise HTTPException(404)
```

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: See if this helps at all: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3855

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the MongoDB driver, updating that fixed the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).